# How to convert html code in database to plain-text in fpdf output in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xampp, tinymce, fpdf

I hate lengthy questions,but as i am *new to PHP* im writing full code.Please Bare me.

I'm trying to generate a **Invoice in PHP in Xampp** which contains "tinymce text editor" in the form ,which im using to edit content.
Here is the create.php page

```
  <script src='js/tinymce.min.js'></script>
  <script>
  tinymce.init({
      selector: '#mytextarea',  
        plugins: [
                  'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
                  'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
                  'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
                ],

      a_plugin_option: true,
      a_configuration_option: 400
    });

  </script>
```

The content i am editing in Editor is a table with nxn cells, but the data ***is saving in the database in HTML code.***

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Sl.NO</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
        <td>Some more TExt</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
        <td>Some more TExt</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

when i am retrieving the data into read.php,Output is coming as expected.
[Image of read.php](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/202528/3243661/335hT5kCWBAoT5F/Captured.JPG)

But when im generating the page into pdf using fpdf, the output is like this,
[not as expected](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/202528/3243661/Y5Ezg3wpPpy6BTP/Captured2.JPG)

I tried both html_entity_decode and strip_tags also `html_entity_decode(strip_tags($data['content']))`

I just want the pdf to be same as read.php.. Just help me,in what i need to concentrate to get what i want ,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Might be helpful:http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-php-with-fpdf_447.html

Comment: Hi sinto ,Thanks for the response,
 I tried it already 7days ago,
But here i want to print dynamic tables instead of fixed number of rows and columns.
(i.e user may enter nxn cells), i am just banging my head in search of **"how to convert htmldata in database into plain-text in pdf in php" **
Help me out if you get any solution .

Answer (score 1):

When trying to convert html to pdf I found `wkhtml` to be the best free tool available. It can be found at http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ or installed via linux package manager (usually via `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`) on many distributions. The benefit of this tool is that it uses the webkit browser engine to really render the webpage like a browser would do, including html and css. This implies that you can use all available css styling to format your invoice.

If your php interpreter can access and execute the wkhtmltopdf file than conversion is as simple as this:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://your.domain/read.php /my/path/invoice.pdf
```

In php you ccan do this by using `exec()`

```
$url = escapeshellarg('http://your.domain/read.php');
$filePath = escapeshellarg('/my/path/invoice.pdf');
exec('wkhtmltopdf ' . $url . ' ' . $filePath);
```

Alternatives:

1. Use a library like `fpdf` for pdf creation. You'll have to create plain text values from your html on your own. This will give you flexibility but you have to handle the data completely on your own.
2. There are some libraries out there that promise to convert html directly to pdf. All of those libraries will only implement a subset of html/css so you will have to adopt your styling to meet the capabilities of the library in use.

Comment: Will try this right away and let you know. Appreciate your taking time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

actual this is not a complete answer. Just sharing an idea:
html page

```
<div id="htmltable">
    <table>....</table>
</div>
```

In a js file get content from div  and pass it to the place where PDF is generating:

```
htmltable = $( "#htmltable" ).html();
```

Get the passed html data from js:

```
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$htmlTable = '<div id="htmltable"><table>....</table></div>';
$pdf->WriteHTML2($htmlTable);
$pdf->Output();
```